# Nuances between "avoir pour habitude de faire" and "avoir l'habitude de faire"

Tags: sens

I just said in conversation:

> Mais si tu crois qu’elle ***a pour habitude de*** te tirer d'affaire, détrompe-toi.

But how does it compare to the following construction, exactly?

> Mais si tu crois qu’elle ***a  l'habitude de*** te tirer d'affaire, détrompe-toi.

---

This question probably extends to other similar cases, such as:

> "avoir pour vocation de faire" vs "avoir vocation à faire"

Interestingly, though, as for the "but", there is no corresponding expression:

> "avoir pour but de faire" vs "???"

Comment: With *vocation* the difference lies in *vocation **de*** or *vocation **à***. You can't draw any parallel with  ***pour** habitude de* /  *habitude de*. It should be a different question altogether.

Comment: @Laure: There is a parallel to be made. The preposition *de* is attached to *avoir* in *avoir pour … de*. Whereas in the other kind of sentences you'd use the preposition that comes along with the noun. (*But* having none.)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez *vocation et que *vocation de* et *vocation à* ne sont pas interchangeables.  *Avoir pour vocation de* peut se dire, *avoir pour vocation à* ne se dit pas il me semble... Je ne vois vraiment pas le parallèle avec l'habitude / d'habitude, mais si quelqu'un le voit il le dira sans nul doute.

Comment: @Laure: *Vocation* admet les deux prépositions avec des sens distincts, mais aucune des deux n'est utilisée dans *avoir pour vocation de*.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je ne comprends pas ce que tu veux dire, je pense qu'il y a quelque chose qui m'échappe....

Comment: @Laure: La construction *avoir pour x de* est utilisée indépendament des prépositions qui peuvent être attachées à x. Exemples possibles: *la vocation*, *l'avantage* (de¹/à faire qqch). *la prédisposition* (à faire qqch), *la conséquence*, *l'objectif*, *l'envie* (de¹ faire qqch), *le but* (habituellement pas de complément). Tous ces noms peuvent être utilisés dans la construction *avoir pour x de²*, et le sens qui en résulte est différent. Ce *de²* n'est pas le même que le *de¹* qui est attaché au nom. La différence entre *vocation de* et *vocation à* n'importe pas pour cette question.

Comment: @Laure: Sois plus claire, je ne comprends pas ce que tu dis. Si tu veux on pourrait ajouter l'exemple suivant à la question qui élargit le parallèle. Quelle est la différence entre « elle a une prédisposition à faire ça » et  « elle a pour prédisposition de faire ça ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Pour moi la question ne porte pas sur *avoir pour* mais *avoir (pour) **habitude de*** . Ou alors elle est mal posée au départ, et c'est pour ça que j'ai souligné le fait qu'on ne pouvait faire de parallèle sans expliciter la différence de sens entre *vocation de* et *vocation à* .

Comment: Je ne peux pas faire plus clair désolée. Il y a pour moi deux questions. La question du titre et de départ  sur *avoir (pour) **habitude de***. Et ensuite une autre question sur *avoir pour* (vocation, but, etc...).

Comment: Pourquoi mets-tu ce *pour* entre parenthèses ? *avoir habitude de* ne se dit pas. Il y a deux choix : utiliser la construction *avoir pour … de*, ou ne pas l'utiliser, et dans ce cas il y a plein de possibilités pour introduire le nom selon le cas (article défini, indéfini, ou pas d'article) suivi d'une préposition (parfois au choix) acceptée par ce nom et une clause infinitive. La question porte sur la différence entre utiliser la construction et ne pas l'utiliser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La plupart du temps *avoir pour habitude de* et *avoir l'habitude de* sont interchangeables. À mon avis c'est le cas dans l'exemple de la question. Mais on peut cependant voir des nuances.

« J'ai l'habitude de faire du vélo » peut aussi bien dire que **je sais** faire du vélo que le fait j'en fasse **régulièrement**.

> -Tu sais faire du vélo ?
>    -Oui, bien sûr, j'ai l'habitude d'en faire.

Je n’emploierais pas « j'ai pour habitude » dans ce cas. « J'ai pour habitude de faire du vélo » ne signifie qu'indirectement que je sais en faire, mais on attend autre chose après.

> J'ai l'habitude de faire les courses à vélo. → Je fais ça régulièrement.

> J'ai pour habitude de faire les courses à vélo. → J'informe de façon que je fais les courses à vélo par opposition implicite à d'autres moyens de locomotion (à pied ou en voiture...).

Voici [une explication](http://activitesfle.over-blog.com/2015/04/avoir-l-habitude-de-avoir-pour-habitude-de.html), qui recoupe la mienne en partie, mais que je ne trouve pas toujours claire :

> "*Avoir l'habitude de*" et "*avoir pour habitude de*" sont deux expressions très proches. Dans beaucoup de cas, elles peuvent être utilisées de façon équivalente l'une à l'autre.
>   *Exemple*:
>   J'ai l'habitude de me coucher à 23 heures.
>   J'ai pour habitude de me coucher à 23 heures.
>
> Cependant, elles possèdent une petite nuance. Les deux expressions ne peuvent pas toujours être utilisées de façon équivalente.
>
> "**Avoir l'habitude de**" est l'expression qui peut être utilisée dans le plus grand nombre de sens différents de "*habitude*". Cela peut correspondre à une manière ordinaire, habituelle de faire, à une aptitude, à un degré d'adaptation à une situation ou un état, à une dépendance ou une façon de faire habituelle, souvent répétée.
>    *exemple*: j'ai l'habitude de me faire obéir.
>
> "**Avoir pour habitude de**" est un expression qui ne peut être utilisée que dans une situation où l'on veut mettre en avant l'aspect "répété" de l'"*habitude*". ("avoir l'habitude de" peut également être utilisé dans ce cas) 
>   *exemple*: j'ai pour habitude de mettre du lait dans mon café. (c'est ce que je fais d'habitude; généralement, quand je prends du café, je mets du lait)
>
> Ainsi, si l'on dit par exemple: "j'ai pour habitude de fumer", l'on fait référence à la répétition de l'action. L'on ajoutera ainsi plutôt un contexte pour préciser l'idée: "j'ai pour habitude de fumer après le repas".
>   La phrase "j'ai l'habitude de fumer" hors contexte pourra autant signifier cette idée de répétition que la dépendance à la cigarette, ou même que l'expression du fait que l'on sait fumer (aptitude).