# What's the French equivalent for "oversharing"

Tags: traduction, demande-de-mot

I'm wondering how you translate a sentence like "I have a habit of oversharing to complete strangers". None of the French dictionaries I use seem to have this word in their database.

Here's my attempt at translating "I have a habit of oversharing to complete strangers", J'ai l'habitude de partager trop avec des parfaits inconnus.

Comment: Oversharing is a verb here. In a dictionary you have to look for the infinitive of a verb (and not V-ing). Still, even knowing that, you will not find "overshare" in lots of all English dictionaries, let alone bilingual ones.You have to break the word down: [prefix over](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/over) + [share](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/share). Verification: [I have a habit of oversharing to complete strangers](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#en/fr/I%20have%20a%20habit%20of%20oversharing%20to%20complete%20strangers).

Comment: Sorry I can't access that site, my wifi has some weird setting where the large majority of translators are blocked, could you directly tell me what the translator says?

Comment: Why don't you try putting a sentence together in French and then we'd tell you if it is correct. [The purpose of the site is to help people and explain](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  rather than translating as such.

Comment: oversharing is a **newish, colloquial term**. That's why it's not in the dictionary. Ergo, one has to work out a translation. When English speakers say: Thank you for sharing. That has become a cliché of pop psychology. I can think of at least four ways of saying that in French. oversharing means telling people too much about your personal problems or concerns.

Comment: @Lambie Why not sharing these four ways with the rest of us?

Comment: @None I've attempted a translation, could you check it?

Comment: Do you mean online by sharing photos and the like or just disclosing too much information when you talk to people live?

Comment: @escarlateadamantine, I meant disclosing too much information

Comment: overshare in English means to share too much **personal information** about oneself. In French, you have to say that bit otherwise you can't translate the meaning. And over is trop. So, you get: **J'ai l'habitude de partager trop d'informations personnelles avec des personnes que je connais pas**.  parfaits inconnus is great but the wrong register for the English.

Comment: @Lambie Quelle différence de registre tu fais entre *de parfaits inconnus* et *des personnes que je ne connais pas* ?

Comment: J'utiliserais le terme "se répendre" : j'ai l'habitude de me répendre. Néanmoins, je ne suis pas sûr que ce soit compris par tous.

Comment: @LoïcDiBenedetto Est-ce que vous vouliez dire "se répandre" au lieu de "se répendre"? Google n'a aucun de résultats quand je recherche "se répendre".

Comment: En effet, belle faute d'orthographe de ma part^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is perfectly understandable but it can be improved.

- **Placing the adverb**
  *trop* being a short adverb we would rather place it before the infinitive<sup>1</sup>.
- **De** parfaits inconnus
  The article *de* is used instead of *des* when the noun it determines is preceded by an adjective.
  So we could have: *j'ai l'habitude de trop partager avec de parfais inconnus.*
- About ***partager***
  *trop partager* could be an option, but *trop partager* hasn't acquired in French the meaning "overshare" has over the past 20 years. French has not yet established a standard way of saying we reveal an (often inappropriate) amount of details about our personal life, which is what [oversharing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/overshare) is about.

If the information you share is just about yourself (which oversharing usually is) you could say:

- *J'ai l'habitude de **trop parler de moi** avec de parfaits inconnus*.
- *J'ai l’habitude de **trop me confier** à de parfaits inconnus.*
- *J'ai l’habitude de **trop me dévoiler** à de parfaits inconnus.*

If you mean that the information you share isn't only about yourself then I would suggest :

- *J'ai l'habitude de dévoiler trop d'informations à de parfaits inconnus.*

In any of these examples  *avoir l'habitude de* could be replaced by *avoir pour habitude de*. The difference between the two is really very slight and in this particular sentence it would not make any difference. A post [there](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26640/358) explaining the difference, when one can be perceived.

<sup><sup>1</sup>This remark cannot be generalised, placing the adverb is quite subtle in French.</sup>

Comment: What you say about trop partager is not semantically true. J'ai tendance à trop partager des informations. personnelles. It works fine and is completely French.